# xaml / c# stackpanel with background rectangle

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

I have a list (ListBox) of items in XAML using a StackPanel- based element template. The layout is fine, but I would now like to have a rectangle as a background for each item - creating a box around each one.

I was thinking of using a Canvas somehow, but as each item's height varies (as well as the height of the items inside the StackPanel), I'm not sure how to do it (I'm new to C#/XAML). What would be the best composition for the template in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just specify it in an `ItemTemplate` and it will do what you want, something like;

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>

    <Grid>
       <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2" Background="Blue"/>
       <!-- Insert the rest of your Item template stuff here -->
    </Grid>

  </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: this will work if you put `Border` and `StackPanel` in a `Grid`

Comment: Touché @dkozl +1 thats what I get for answering super quick and forgetting the one content rule. Updating now...

Answer (score 0):

ListBox is a type of [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx), which exposes several properties to control the appearance of the items.  In this case, have a look at ItemContainerStyle (in the case of ListBox, the item containers are instances of ListBoxItem).  You could, for instance, set the Background property in an ItemsContainerStyle to some color.